# How to assign data returned from $promise to global variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I've two services, `service1 and service2`, and I would like to invoke a method of `service1` into `service2`.

Ideally, I would like to assign the returned data from `service1.getMethod()` to a global variable declared as `var result = []`.

Here is the code:

### service1

```
.factory('service1', function (dependencies...) {
    var getMethod1 = function () {
       ...//making http get call
       return deferred.promise();
    };

    return {
       getMethod1 : getMethod1
    };
});
```

### service2

```
.factory('service2', function (dependencies...) {
    var result = [];

    var getMethod2 = function () {
        Service1.getMethod1().then(function (data) {
            result = data;
    });

    //RUN METHOD
    getMethod2();

    //Here ideally, I would like result to contain `[object, object, object]`
    console.log(result); //instead it prints `undefined`
});
```

So ideally, I would like to use what's will be in `result` in `service2's` other `functions` `i.e. result[0].name` etc. Not sure if what I'm doing is the right approach.

Please provide an `plunker demo or code snippet` example and if not sure about something, please write comment below.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't work with asynchronous code like you are attempting. `result` variable is simply not yet populated when you are trying to use it. Instead you should make `getMethod2` return promise too, and use its `then` method:

```
.factory('service2', function (dependencies...) {

    var getMethod2 = function () {
        return Service1.getMethod1();
    };

    // RUN METHOD
    getMethod2().then(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

You can also cache returned data:

```
.factory('service2', function (dependencies...) {

    var result;

    var getMethod2 = function () {
        return result ? $q.when(result) : Service1.getMethod1().then(function(data) {
            result = data;
            return result;
        });
    };

    // RUN METHOD
    getMethod2().then(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

Comment: Is there a different approach to achieve somehow storing returned into object array so that I can used it across the service?

Comment: Sure you can cache returned value.